# How do I solder that? The solder won't stick

Tags: soldering

I have those four holes and I need to somehow make a good connection with them and the Arduino. I'm using a jumper wire and I'm trying to solder it but the solder won't stick. I don't know what to do. Is it possible to do with household items (because coronavirus doesn't allow me to go out and shops are probably closed)? I don't have a solder paste.

[image]

Comment: Flux + proper heat (not too hot, not too cold) (read the labels on your solder wire). Clean your connections (flux helps remove oxidation, but only so much). Or maybe honestly just use regular wire?

Comment: Cut the pin off and solder the bare wire

Comment: I think I'll try with bare wire.

Comment: Regular solder should have all the flux you need to solder a normal wire to those holes.  Is the solder  sticking to the holes or to the wire, or is it not sticking to anything?

Comment: I don't see anything in that picture that even looks like you might have tried to solder it.  I'd expect to see something, even just a little flux left over from applying solder to the joint.

Comment: What won't the solder tick to?  The pad?  The pin?

Comment: There are some pictures of how to solder wires to a PCB [here.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/howtosolder-8throughhole)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. Detail from OP's photo.*

There is no sign of a soldering attempt on this joint.

- Apply the solder-wetted soldering iron tip to the PCB pad and the pin simultaneously for a couple of seconds to heat it up.
- Feed in a suitable guage solder with flux core until the joint and the pad are wetted.
- Withdraw the soldering iron and allow the joint to cool.